# $Q^* D Q = P^* C P$ implies $Q^* D^x Q = P^* C^x P$ ??

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $Q^* D Q = P^* C P$ for $D,C\in GL_n(\Bbb C)$ diagonal matrices with positive real numbers on the diagonals, and $P,Q\in U(n)$.

Does this imply $$Q^* D^x Q = P^* C^x P$$ for $x \in \Bbb R$? It is easy to see that the answer is yes if $x \in \Bbb N$ but I'm not sure about real $x$.

Comment: $(Q^*DQ)(Q^*DQ)=Q^*D\cdot QQ^*\cdot DQ=\ldots $

Comment: Note that your condition implies $C=D$.

Comment: @Surb: it doesn't, $P$ and $Q$ can be some kind of permutation matrices.

Comment: @John you are right, we have $C=D$ up to permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negative $x$ you need the matrices to be invertible, but then it is easy to see that it holds for negative integers.

It is also easy to check that it holds for $x=1/n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, using the uniqueness of roots for positive matrices. Then you can multiply the matrices to show that it holds for arbitrary positive fractions. And then by continuity it should hold for all real $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If matrix $M$ has positive eigenvalues then for any real $x$ the function $M\to M^x$  can be defined. If in particular $M=Q^{-1}DQ$ is diagonasable with positive numbers on diagonal then this definition coincides with equality $M^x=Q^{-1}D^xQ$

Comment: This is true, but it seems that it is exactly the point of OP to prove that the definition is consistent with the representation of the matrix.